# I need help with Pantheon

Tags: session, configure, pantheon

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I tried just straight up installing Pantheon-shell, needless to say it's pretty dysfunctional without any configuration (then some things happened and stuff and now i'm back to a clean install)

So my question is: Has anyone seen a guide on getting pantheon-shell running proper-like in Ubuntu? if not does anyone know how I could go about working it out?

Sub-unimportant-question: I also have steam installed as a desktop session and i was wondering if there was anyway to select which screen it uses.

Thanks guys

sudo apt-get Answers

Comment: You should have on post per question

Comment: Since elementary Luna is based off 12.04 I can say that it runs fine, having tried Wingpanel and Plank and the rest of the elementary software on 12.10 I can tell you it also runs fine. Since you don't *exactly* tell us what problems you have we can't help you further. Also since it's software that is not stable, and it's in development getting updates all days you should *report* the issues in Launchpad.

Comment: I'll reinstall it and post screenshots of the issues

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple installation explanations, but in case you've missed it:
[Tutorial](http://linuxmotion.com/tutorials/73-how-to-install-pantheon-desktop-enviroment-in-ubuntu-12-10)
It's for 12.10 but should work the same.

From what I've read elementary is still in heavy development and while I use some elements on a xfce install, I cannot really talk about the whole shell.
Good luck,

Comment: Does pantheon files work well on 13.04?

Comment: I actually have no idea. I'm using pantheon on archlinux on another computer.